# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'Bookdetails'. Did you forget to specify values ['book_id']?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, python-requests

I have been trying to debug this problem and I have seen some similar threads with the same issue, but even after cross checking all the options, I seem to have the problem still.

I am using the following:

**application.py**

```
@app.route("/Booksearch/<int:book_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def Bookdetails(book_id):

if request.method == "GET":
    if session["Username"] is None:
        return render_template("error.html", message="Some error message.")
    else:
        return render_template("some.html")
```

**inside my HTML**

```
<a href="{{ url_for('Bookdetails', books_id=result.id) }}">
```

When I click on the link, I can see the correct `book_id` on the browser (`/Booksearch/123 where book_id=123`). I am not sure what I am doing wrong to still get the following error.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `books_id` when creating the URL, but the endpoint expects the parameter to be named `book_id` (without the `s`):

```
def Bookdetails(book_id): <- without s
```

While in your template you have:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('Bookdetails', books_id=result.id) }}">  <- with s in books
```

Use the correct form instead:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('Bookdetails', book_id=result.id) }}">
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I m sorry I forgot to correct that before posting my question. I always had my variable as book_id but I was playing around with the name just to see if that made any difference (changing to books_id from book_id). Originally my code is the way you are suggesting and I still have the error.

Comment: The error is telling you that you have a call to `url_for('Bookdetails')` where `book_id` isn't included. Either because of misspelling like in your question, or because you haven't included it in the arguments. Without having the relevant information (i.e. the thing it's actually complaining about in that case) -- and you having the actual error in your question makes it impossible to say anything more.